# Comparing two xml files and get the differences

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to compare two XML files. My requirement is to compare old and new xml files and if any difference is there merge it into the new xml file.

Below code snippet gives me whether both files are equal or not.

```
public static void compare() throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    dbf.setCoalescing(true);
    dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
    dbf.setIgnoringComments(true);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc1 = db.parse(new File("old.xml"));
    doc1.normalizeDocument();

    Document doc2 = db.parse(new File("new.xml"));
    doc2.normalizeDocument();

   System.out.println (doc1.isEqualNode(doc2));
}
```

But I want the differences also. Please tell me how I can get the differences.

I have already tried [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/userguide/html/index.html) , but I dont want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jaxb to parse your xml and contruct java objects with unmarshall method and compare your generated objects.

See it here : [How to compare jaxb, object, string to find differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37946880/how-to-compare-jaxb-object-string-to-find-differences)

You can also use google diff-match-patch api to compare your two xml as Strings  and patch to create the new.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-diff-match-patch/

Diff demo : https://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html
Patch Demo : https://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_patch.html

Sources are available on github : https://github.com/GerHobbelt/google-diff-match-patch

Comment: In my case the xml is in different format :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<spring:beans>.... </spring:beans> <model>...</model> , I have multiple tags like this.

Comment: Is there any way in java itself to achieve this. I dont want to use the 3rd party api. Cant we make use of DocumentBuilderFactory ??

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, it's not so easy to make a diff of two files. I think it's your best choice to use a tested and good api.